# Showing Isomorphism between $R$ and $R^2$ where $R=\operatorname{End}(K(V))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Consider the ring $R = \operatorname{End}\big(K(V )\big). $

Prove that the free left $R-$modules $R$ and $R^2$ are isomorphic.

I was able to do this when $V$ is a countably infinite dimension vector space over the field $K$.For that I used the bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^2$.

Can someone help me in the case when $V$ is an uncountably infinite dimensional vector space over $K$.

Answer (score 1):

For any infinite set $B$ we have $|B|=|B|^2$ where $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality. So in your case let $B$ be a basis of $V$ as a $K$-vector space, take $\phi : B \to B^2$ a bijection and the rest of your proof can remain the same.

If you are interested in the intricacies of this bijection, this is a set theory question. The proof that I know consists of first establishing $|B|^2 \leq  |B|$ via ordinal induction and then appealing to Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein's theorem.